# Differences between "Verb + Adj", "Adj + Verb", "Verb + 得 + Adj" and "Adj + 地 + Verb"?

Tags: grammar, meaning, usage, difference, sentence-structure

I am having some difficulties understanding the differences in meaning between the following structures (the examples are from [Line dictionary](https://dict.naver.com/linedict/zhendict/)):

1. `Verb + Adj`

   e.g:

   > **走快**了她会累。
   >
   > **Zŏu kuài** le tā huì lĕi.
   >
   > Walking quickly tires her.
2. `Adj + Verb`

   e.g:

   > 我们**快走**。
   >
   > Wŏmen **kuài zŏu**.
   >
   > Let's go!
3. `Verb + 得 + Adj`

   e.g:

   > 你的表**走得快**，还是走得慢?
   >
   > Nĭ de biăo **zŏudékuài**，háishì zŏudémàn?
   >
   > Does your watch gain or lose?
4. `Adj + 地 + Verb`

   e.g:

   > 一个打杂的很**快地走**过来了。
   >
   > Yīgè dăzá de hĕn**kuài dì zŏu** guòlái le.
   >
   > Very soon a cleaner marched over.

I know this topic has been asked partially (except structures 1. and 2.) in:

[Difference in MEANING (NOT structure) between 得 vs 地](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/q/10596/25265)

[what is difference using of "地" and "得"](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/q/10235/25265)

[的-地-得, when do you use which?](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/q/89/25265)

Comment: Are you sure it is Verb + Adj? [走(v) + 快了(adv) | 我们(n) + 快(adv) + 走(verb) | 很快地(adv) +走过 (verb)] | 走(v) + 得(potential particle) + 快 (adv)]

Comment: I don't understand your question.  You already got the meanings of those sentences. You should know the difference in meaning from those English translations.

Comment: @dan I just copied some examples from the dictionary but I don't completely understand the differences of the meanings. I expected an answer that would first explain in general the meaning of the structures and then link to these particular examples (or some others) to explain them.

Comment: @TangHo I used "Adj" purely for terminology (I didn't know how to express the structures otherwise), even though they might have a different grammatical function there. An otherwise adjective working as the verb in a sentence can be referred as *adjectival verb* (maybe analogously we can use the term *adjectival adverb* for adverbs derived from adjectives).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will suggest my ideas (probably there are some mistakes, so please point them out). For each case I believe there can be several possibilities.

1. `Verb + Adj` :

   - `Adj` is an adverb **[defining or restricting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relative_clause#Restrictive_and_non-restrictive)** the meaning of the `Verb`. For example,

     > 一个人会走快很多，但两个人好像更有趣。
     >
     > Yīgèrén huì zǒu kuài hěnduō, dàn liǎng gè rén hǎoxiàng gèng yǒuqù.
     >
     > One person walks a lot faster, but two people seem to be more interesting.

     Here, 快很多 is an adverb that specifies a relevant characteristic of the verb *to walk*. The important idea is not *to walk* but *to walk a lot faster*.
   - The `... + Verb` is the **subject** of the adjectival verb `Adj`. For example:

     > 我们出去好。
     >
     > Wǒmen chūqù hǎo.
     >
     > It would be good if we go out.

     Here, 我们出去 (we go out) is the subject of the adjectival verb 好 (is good).
   - The `Adj` is the **direct object** of the `Verb`. For example:

     > 我觉得很惭愧。
     >
     > Wǒ juédé hěn cánkuì.
     >
     > I feel very embarassed.

     Here, 很惭愧 (very embarassed) is the direct object of the verb 觉得 (to feel).
2. `Adj + Verb`:

   - If the `Adj` is an **adverb of time**, it signals the time of the action. Such is the case of 快 which can also mean *soon*. For example:

     > 他快回来了。
     >
     > Tā kuài huíláile.
     >
     > He'll be back soon.
   - The `Adj` is actually a **verb**. For example:

     > 我每天都努力学习.
     >
     > Wǒ měitiān dū nǔlì xuéxí.
     >
     > I study hard every day.

     努力 is a verb meaning *to make a great effort*. So here we have `Verb + Verb` and 学习 is the direct object of the verb 努力: *to make a great effort studying*.
   - The `Adj` is placed in the **topic position** but the underlying structure is `Verb + Adj`. For example:

     > 这道题很难解。
     >
     > Zhè dào tí hěn nán jiě.
     >
     > This problem is difficult to solve.

     Here, 这道题很难 is the object + verb placed in the topic position. We can rearrange the sentence to its "natural" order:

     > 解这道题很难。
     >
     > Jiě zhè dào tí hěn nán.
     >
     > It is difficult to solve this problem.

     We see that actually 解这道题 (to solve this problem) is the subject of the adjectival verb 很难 (very difficult).
3. `Verb + 得 + Adj`: The adjective **describes** (instead of restricting) **the manner or the result** of the state of an action. For example:

   > 他走得很慢。
   >
   > Tā zǒu dé hěn màn.
   >
   > He walks (in a manner) very slowly.

   > 他教得累了。
   >
   > Tā jiào de lèile.
   >
   > He taught so much (to the result) that he is tired.
4. `Adj + 地 + Verb`: The `Adj + 地` is an adverb that **defines or restricts** the **manner** in which the action is carried in a **particular situation**. Because of this, it can be used for commands. For example:

   > 你快快地跑。
   >
   > Nǐ kuài kuài dì pǎo.
   >
   > Run quickly!

Answer (score 0):

The thing about descriptive phrases is, you can almost always leave them out. They are useful but unnecessary for minimal communication. If you have a long, complicated sentence, try to remove all descriptive phrases, then it will be much easier to understand.

1. 走快了她会累。-> 走了她会累。
   (If she) walks fast she gets tired. -> (If she) walks she gets tired.

You can gloss this as:

Walking fast makes her tired -> Walking makes her tired.

'Walking' is a gerund, a noun. 走 is then the Chinese equivalent of 'Walking' here.

2. 我们快走。-> 我们走。

We're leaving soon. -> We're leaving.
'leaving' is a gerundive, an adjective, but you can't leave it out too or you will be left with: We're.
(Nice to know you exist, but not much information)

3. 你的表走得快，还是走得慢? -> 你的表走得，还是走得? -> 你的表走，还是走?

(reductio ad absurdum, no information. You need the 得快、得慢 = how)

Does your watch go fast or go slow? -> Does your watch go or go?
(fast and slow are the 'how' in 'Your watch goes how'?)

4. 一个打杂的很快地走过来了。-> 一个打杂的走过来了。
   A worker quickly came over. -> A worker came over.

(All these '->', I think I'm back in PHP!)